# Why do I get a different runtime when using DataContext.ExecuteQuery with implicit versus explicit parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a table containing test assembly statistics of TFS builds as follows:

```
AssemblyName   Duration      TestResults    MsPerResult Branch
Ass1.dll            100                2             50     $/branch1
Ass2.dll            200                2            100     $/branch1/sub1
Ass3.dll            400                2            200     $/branch1/sub1/subsub1
...
```

Additionally I have a summary class for holding a DataContext.ExecuteQuery<> result

```
public class AssemblyStatistics
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public int TestResultCount { get; set; }
    public long ValueInMs { get; set; }
}
```

If I execute the following code, my query always takes the same time, even if I limit the results querying a subbranch only:

```
context.ExecuteQuery<AssemblyStatistics>(
  "SELECT TOP 10 AssemblyName, SUM(Duration) AS ValueInMs, SUM(TestResults) AS TestResultCount FROM AssembliesByDuration WHERE Branch LIKE {0} GROUP BY AssemblyName ORDER BY SUM(Duration) DESC", "$/branch1/sub1%").ToList();
```

however using the following (not websafe) format, the runtime goes down as expected

```
context.ExecuteQuery<AssemblyStatistics>(
  @"SELECT TOP 10 AssemblyName, SUM(Duration) AS ValueInMs, SUM(TestResults) AS TestResultCount FROM AssembliesByDuration WHERE Branch LIKE '"
                  + "$/branch1/sub1%" + "' GROUP BY AssemblyName ORDER BY SUM(Duration) DESC").ToList();
```

Am I missing something or is this just an issue with Linq2SQL evaluating the LIKE afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the single quotes marks around {0} in the first query.

Comment: Using single quotes does not return any results at all. The data returned by both queries is the same...